# Using javascript to animate graph with scroll?

Tags: javascript, graph, scroll

I wanna draw up a graph with js, and then animate it when the graph is in the viewport. And, i want it to animate by scroll. Have no idea where to begin, is there maybe a pre-made library for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used some different graphing javascript libraries myself.

I could suggest the following two. they might solve your problem :)

1) http://www.highcharts.com/

2) http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close, but, i need it to be animated by scrolling. Like every time i turn the scroll-wheel, it animatas 1 more frame in. Poor explenation, sorry.. :P